# How to remove cellSpacing. table CellSpacing is zero, not work

Tags: c#, wpf, cellspacing

```
Table tb = new Table();
tb.CellSpacing = 0;
```

I set table's CellSpacing 0. but line between cell and cell still remain.
line is so thin. but still exist.

I want to remove that blank or line. How should I do?

Comment: please provide your code so we can help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the border thickness ?

ThicknessConverter tc = new ThicknessConverter();

tb.BorderThickness = (Thickness)tc.ConvertFromString("0in");

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
i tried changed all of border thickness, magin, padding possible changing.....
hm.. is different new Thickness(0) and ThicknessConverter??

it's still remain very thin space between cells